# How to accomplish the following emboss effect with css

Tags: css

Is it possible to have the same effect that this image has with pure CSS?  It doesn't have to be a perfect match, but something that is close enough so I don't have to depend on such images...

[image]

thanks.  It looks like the lightness of the gradient angles cut in towards the edges...and the same light gradient drops down a couple pixels from the top...

Comment: You might be able to have a gradient from top-to-bottom for the lighting, then apply a diagonal "gradient" to erase away the angles.

Comment: That is one of the issues I have discovered...how do you get "2" top diagonal gradients on the same element?

Comment: Check out jqueryMobile, They do this effect with pure css

Comment: Bryon I am not doubting your expertise, but I have been working with jQuery Mobile for over a year and have not found anything like that on their buttons, or API demos.  CSS diagonal gradients appear to be linear only one way... If you happen to come across a source the reflects your point, please share.  Thanks

Comment: @blackhawk You can have multiple background images, each one being a gradient. If I remember correctly, you define them in order from top to bottom. So you would define your diagonal ones first, then the "light" one, and finally put a solid-colour blue background.

Comment: thanks @Kolink, that is my backup plan, but it would be nice if this could be done without images, and instead with css3 effects.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. `background-image:linear-gradient(...);`

Answer (score 0):

With no css gradients, here's something that's embossed, but not the bevel in your example:

```
<div style="background:#1d1d88;width:200px;height:50px;border-radius:10px;box-shadow: inset 0px -5px 20px 8px #060618;"></div>
```

It works best with a little border radius.  If you want to add a gradient, I recommend http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Here's a quick class with a gradient:

```
.bevelish {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px -5px 30px 3px #000052;
    background: #2f2e59;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2f2e59 40%, #00003d 60%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(40%,#2f2e59), color-stop(60%,#00003d));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2f2e59 40%,#00003d 60%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2f2e59 40%,#00003d 60%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2f2e59 40%,#00003d 60%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2f2e59 40%,#00003d 60%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2f2e59', endColorstr='#00003d',GradientType=0 );
}
```

The key is the inset in the box-shadow, and there's also I believe a 5th parameter you can add, a pixel value, for strength of the shadow, so you can play with the values and try to approach something beveled, but I'm not sure you can make it a "sharp" bevel.